# Converting to a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

firstly apologies, as I have seen this question asked before, but I'm still none the wiser, so going to have to ask it myself.
I am very new to html5 and css3, so far I have managed to get by, until now.

I would like to convert one of the options in my navigation menu to a drop down menu, I have tried many times using info from here and other sites, but I'm still having problems.

Here is my css for the Nav menu..

```
    /* Site Nav */

    #site-nav
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
}

    #site-nav ul
    {
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        #site-nav ul li
        {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            height: 90px;
            line-height: 110px;
            margin: 0 0 0 1.75em;
        }

            #site-nav ul li a
            {
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
                outline: 0;
            }

            #site-nav ul li a:hover
            {
                color: #fff;
            }

        #site-nav ul li.current_page_item
        {
            background: url('images/nav-arrow.png') center 77px no-repeat;
        }

            #site-nav ul li.current_page_item a
            {
                color: #662d91;
            }
```

and here is the html for my menu...

```
    <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                                <li><a href="bullion.html">Bullion</a></li>
                                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#.html">Contact Us</a></li>

                            </ul>
```

If this can be done with just HTML5 and CSS3 then that is great, but I'm happy to go down the JavaScript route if needs be.

Thanks in advance for any help, it will be very much appreciated.

**EDIT 21/03/2013...**

I have tried to implement the code given to me below, and this fiddle shows how far i have got, http://jsfiddle.net/2rgSP/1/
With 2 problems, firstly, links are pushed off edge of website, 2, the drop down menu falls behind the main wrapper. 
There is clearly some conflicting css going on, but i am a complete beginner at this, so I'm clueless I'm afraid.
Hopefully someone can see where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Lee

Comment: Is javascript not an option, Do you just want to accomplish this via html5 and css3?

Comment: @defau1t JavaScript is an option, to be honest, I'm happy to go with what ever will work, as I'm currently clueless.
if it can be done with just html5 and css3 that would be great, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what you could use, if javsscript/jquery is an option:

```
<ul id="cssdropdown">
    <li class="headLink">Home
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="headLink">About
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="headLink">Contact
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="headLink">Links
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Links1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
#cssdropdown{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;}
.headLink{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:right;
    background-color:#999999;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.headLink ul{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    margin:10px 0 0 -13px;
    padding:0 10px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#CCC;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".headLink").hover(function() {
        $('ul',this).slideToggle();
    });

    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LcYrT/)**

Comment: That's great Thank you! but i am having trouble incorporating it into the above code that I'm using,
when I do it, all the links stack up on the left hand side of my website, which i guess is due to conflicting css.

am i right in thinking i need to replace the old nav part of my css, and if so, i then lose my mobile navigation.

i think im well in over my head here, but appreciate the help, will continue to try different things and let you know how i go.

Comment: ok, so i know have the alignment issue sorted, but the drop down element isnt working..

lets say i call the css file dropsown.css and the JS file dropdown.js

how would i then link to these correctly, i can only assume this is where im going wrong.

thanks @defau1t

Comment: you need to include the jquery as well, use the below url:
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
and you should be home

Comment: is there a way to merge my css and your dropdown css as i only need the "products" option to be drop down, and would like the style left the same for the others, it must be a confliction between the 2 css that's causing the problem.

its also worth noting that the menu needs to be at the front so that it doesn't disappear behind the wrapper below it.

hope this makes sense, sorry for being a pain. your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: you can definitely combine the CSS files. If you could be more specific in explaining the problem by putting fiddle at  www.jsfiddle.net I can take a look into it.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have time right now, but will take a look at fiddle tonight/tomorrow and get back to you once I've done it.
Once again, Thank you!

Comment: scrap that, I made time.. here is a basic fiddle of one page of my site, it is the product option that i want to drop down, over the top of the main wrapper. hopefully this makes more sense than me..  http://jsfiddle.net/2rgSP/

Comment: I have had another go at implementing the code, but still no joy, http://jsfiddle.net/2rgSP/1/ <- this fiddle should show you how far I've got, I've put the css you gave me at the end of my css, changed a few values and this is the closest I can get to what I want.
but you can see that 1, the rest of the links are pushed off the edge of the site, and 2, the drop down menu falls behind the main wrapper. any more suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I think i have sorted out the menu hiding, I now just need the other menu items aligned properly.. http://jsfiddle.net/2rgSP/2/ I'm determined to fix it, and i know I'm getting closer, but could really use some help.

Comment: so close now.. I've got the links aligned, I now just need the dropdown to be one column of links, and ideally, I'd like my "current-item" bit of code working (a small arrow on a bar, pointed at current page) http://jsfiddle.net/2rgSP/3/

Comment: DONE IT.. once I incorporated it into the rest of my site, I just had to do a little bit of tweaking and it all fell into place. I've just got to work on the styling of the dropdown, but I'm pretty sure i can manage that.
Thanks for the original code and help, it really was appreciated! @defau1t

Comment: I am glad that I could help.